# need to locate the clsid for the registered com dll in registry

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, components

I created an COM dll and registered it into the registry. But how can i find the clsid for this registered COM dll in registry. because when i opened the registry in the path HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID, many entries are there. Can you please provide the way to find the way to locate the clsid for my registered dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL might host zero or more coclasses (`CLSIDs`). Do a reverse search, and search DLL path or name under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and you will find zero or more items like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{1C15D484-911D-11D2-B632-00C04F79498E}\InprocServer32
(Default) = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvidctl.dll"
```

And you would read it like this:

- 32-bit CLSID in 64-bit Windows (`Wow6432Node`)
- CLSID `{1C15D484-911D-11D2-B632-00C04F79498E}`
- is hosted by DLL (`InprocServer32`)
- by the library `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvidctl.dll`